# Retrieving posts from a Wall, but without logging into Facebook

Tags: asp.net, facebook

Basically, I would like to include my latest Wall posting on my website.  But, so far, everything I have read needs the visitor to the site to log-in to Facebook which, in theory, would then retrieve their latest Wall post.  In prinicpal, I guess it would be like an RSS Feed.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an infinate session, follow the link!
http://www.henrycipolla.com/blog/2008/02/how-to-create-infinite-sessions-with-the-facebook-platform-api/

This uses PHP though...

http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=211192
<- ASP there

Wiki here:
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Getting_Started:_Understanding_Sessions

Excerpt:

> Facebook deprecated infinite sessions
>   in September, 2008. However, if a user
>   explicitly granted your application an
>   infinite session by logging into your
>   application on the old profile and
>   checking the Keep me logged in check
>   box, you'll continue to have an
>   infinite session for that user.